# Typeset indexed function with parameters

Tags: math-mode, typography, subscripts, variable

I want to typeset something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$f_{A_{n,k}}(\omega)$$

\end{document}
```

I don't know how to make the argument `(\omega)` to be typeset (above) somewhere around `n` and `k`, as in my writing on the paper. In my compiled pdf it is always after the function index.

Here is example of hand-written expression
[image]

vs
[image]

Am I wanting too much? Is it standardized in any way?

Comment: First of all: Don't use `$$...$$`. That's deprecated. Use `\[...\]` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a variant, with `\mathrlap` from `mathtools` and some math kerning:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ f_{{}_{\scriptstyle\mathstrut \mathrlap{\mkern -6mu A^{\phantom{1}}_{n,k}}}}\,(ω) \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The closest to you handwriting seems to be the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\Large

You have
\[
f_{A_{n,k}}(\omega)
\]


You want to
\[
f_{\rlap{\raisebox{-0.7em}{$\scriptstyle A_{n,k}$}}}\,(\omega)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As your notation is unclear for me, the spacing probably needs some corrections. Certainly, then a macro for it may be written.